# Calculate Spearman Correlation on a Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to run a Spearman correlation on data that is currently in a Spark DataFrame.  Currently, only the Pearson correlation calculation is available to operate on columns in a DataFrame.  It appears that I can do a Spearman correlation using Spark's MLlib, but I need to pass two RDD[Double] to the function.  The columns I want to compare are Double according to the current schema.

Is there a way to select the columns I want and make the be an array of Doubles so that I can use the MLlib correlation function to get the Spearman correlation coefficient?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply select columns of interest, extract values and compute statistics:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.Statistics

// Generate some random data
scala.util.Random.setSeed(1)
val df = sc.parallelize(g.sample(1000).zip(g.sample(1000))).toDF("x", "y")


// Select columns and extract values
val rddX = df.select($"x").rdd.map(_.getDouble(0))
val rddY = df.select($"y").rdd.map(_.getDouble(0))

val correlation: Double = Statistics.corr(rddX, rddY, "spearman")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this

```
val firstRDD: RDD[Double] = yourDF.select("field1").map(row => row.getDouble(0))
val secondRDD: RDD[Double] = yourDF.select("field2").map(row => row.getDouble(0))
val corr = Statistics.corr(firstRDD, secondRDD, "spearman")
```